# ActiveMQ memory percentage monitoring alert

Tags: java, memory, activemq-classic, broker

My requirement is, I wanted to raise an alert when activemq memory percent usage reached certain limit.

For example: My activemq memory percent set to 70% of JVM heap space. So when the memory perced reached 65 I want to araise an alert.

How can I acheive through the Java code or any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ exposes a lot of metadata using its [JMX/REST Management API](http://activemq.apache.org/rest.html) interface and [Statistics plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html). Memory usage, consumer count etc are part of the metadata.